# Is it possible to keep track of a random character in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, random

I created a project and I added that swipe gesture thing, my ViewController has a label when I swipe left It replaces my label with random string from my array (It works ok),However when I swipe right I want to see the previous string from my array the problem is that it is a random string so I can’t keep track of it, any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Add the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep track of all the random elements generated, create an `array` `randoms`.

```
var randoms = [String]()
```

Also create a `currentIndex` to keep track of the currently visible element from `randoms`.

```
var currentIndex = 0
```

Add all the randomly generated elements to it on `swipeLeft()`.

```
func swipeLeft() {
    if let randomString = arr.randomElement() {
        randoms.append(randomString)
        currentIndex = randoms.count - 1
        label.text = randomString
    }
}
```

Then on `swipeRight()`, pick the 2nd last element (if exist) from the `randoms` `array` and show on the `label`.

```
func swipeRight() {
    if currentIndex > 0 {
        label.text = randoms[currentIndex - 1]
        currentIndex -= 1
    }
}
```